# Setting showPrintMargin to false not working in React Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

I'm trying to remove the vertical line in my react ace editor:
[image]

I've tried setting the printMargin to false but it doesn't seem to be working. Tried restarting the server too but nothing. I'm also using next.js if that helps.

Here is what that code looks like:

```
import ReactAce from "react-ace-editor";
import React from "react";

    function CodeEditor(props) {
      return (
        <ReactAce
          value={`function onLoad(editor) {
          console.log("i've loaded");
        }`}
          mode="javascript"
          theme="xcode"
          showPrintMargin={false}
          setReadOnly={false}
          setValue={props.value}
          style={{
            height: "500px",
            fontSize: "16px",
          }}
        />
      );
    }
    export default CodeEditor;
```

Comment: added an image for the common vertical line problem. if the vertical line in image is not what you mean, please add a relevant image to show what you're trying to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `react-ace-editor` npm package, which is not the original package for react-ace. that's probably why that option is not supported. instead you should use [react-ace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ace):

```
import ReactAce from 'react-ace';
```

Then it'll work, like this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ace-editor-jqnsdb) .

(uncomment the `showPrintMargin` option to see the change.)